# JS Promises - catch() doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm fetching data from an API in that way, and I'm trying to catch an 404 error on it if the user search for a invalid city but is not working.

```js
const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          setWeather(result);
          setQuery('');
        }).catch(() => console.log("error"));
    }
  }
```

[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

> The Promise returned from `fetch()` **won’t reject on HTTP error status** even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with `ok` status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

You have to use the response parameter provided by `.then(response => {...})` and check `response.ok` or `response.status` to get an 404 (or 500) error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well, as you can see:

```js
    const search = evt => {
        if (evt.key === "Enter") {
          fetch('http://dfsdfsdfdsfsdfdfs.com')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(() => console.log("error"));
        }
      }

      search({key : 'Enter'});
```

But an error code from the server is not considered as an error with `fetch` so you have to parse the response yourself and react accordingly.
You can use `res.ok` that will return true if the status code is in the 200-299 range. For more information you can check the [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object documentation

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the [`docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), since `fetch` doesn't do a catch on `404` or `500` status, you can mimic the behavior by throwing an error and catching in the `catch` section.

```
fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
.then((response) => {
    if(response.status == 404){
        throw '404 page not found';
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then((response) => {
    console.log('your JSON string ',response);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the error that way:

```js
const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          setWeather(result);
          setQuery('');
        }).then((data) => {
          if (data === undefined) {
            alert("City not found");
          }
        });
    }
  }
```